# Executing pytest TestCases in jenkins its giving error as no .py module found

Tags: python, git, selenium, jenkins, pytest

I am trying to execute Testcases imorting from github in jenkins, I have configured correct paths of python so that I could successfully install selenium and pytest using pip.

But I don't know why, when I execute pytest Testcases, it starts executing TraceBack and start executing python lib files and giving me error as no .py module found from those files.

[Here is my console output screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06d1p.png)
[Screen shot of Build environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo4za.png)

Comment: The error message says that the package named `py` is not installed ([this one](https://pypi.org/project/py/)). There seems to be nothing wrong with your test invocation. `py` is a direct dependency of `pytest` and should normally be installed automatically; check whether it's installed by e.g. issuing `pip show py` before starting the tests.

Comment: Hi, I did verify 'pip show py' and 'pip install py' but it is showing it is already installed but I don't know why it is showing no module found while executing Test cases.